# How do I build this specific string manually in python

Tags: python-3.x, string

How do I build this string in python 3?
Need output to look like this.

b'\x02\x0\x33\x11\xc3\x0\x24\x4\x0\x58\x3'

Comment: Perhaps show what you tried already?

Comment: Which string do you want to build?

Comment: And why?  That looks like a string representation of a byte string, but is invalid due to single digits after the \x escape code.   Seems like an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I want to send a command string to my controller.

Comment: I want to send a command string to my controller using python. Need to be in this format. x = b'\x02\x00\x33\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x33\x03' when I do print(x) I get this   b'\x02\x003\x11<\x00B\x04\x00X\x03' which seem to be an interpreter function printing bytes in this format.This is ok.I have all the hex values how do I concatenate them and build a string to look like x.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two characters for the hex number:

```
print(b'\x02\x00\x33\x11\xc3\x00\x24\x04\x00\x58\x03')
```

works as expected.

Comment: print(b'\x02\x00\x33\x11\xc3\x00\x24\x04\x00\x58\x03')
>>>b'\x02\x003\x11\xc3\x00$\x04\x00X\x03'